# How to customize 404 page in django?

Tags: python, django

In my django app I want to show a custom not found 404 page. But after reading the documentation and coding I am still getting the default 404 Not found page.
I am working with Django 2.2.8
I also set DEBUG=False
Here is my code:

in setting.py I have defined:

```
handler404 = 'riesgo.views.views.error_404'
```

Definition in riesgo/views/views.py

```
def error_404(request, exception):
        return render(request,'404.html')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your main `urls.py` file

```
handler404 = 'mysite.views.my_custom_page_not_found_view'
```

you can read the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/views/#customizing-error-views) for a more detailed answer.